# VB6 .dll in ASP.NET Web Service project

Tags: c#, web-services, dll, vb6, asmx

I got a strange problem recently. I have some VB6 .dll that I must use in my ASP.NET Web Service project. When I test the .dll in Console application - all works fine - I create an object and can use all methods as it should be. But when I start to use it in my Web Service I got a strange problem. When I'm creating an instance of dll class - it is created (after a long pause) but all properties instead of being nulls (as it happens when I test it in Console Application) in the debugger are set as "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation". Something competely strange I've never seen before :) And at the same time in my client application (which actually invokes the service) I'm getting a connection reset.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If this DLL was created for a desktop environment, then it may simply not work in a server environment. It may depend on using a Windows message loop for synchronization, and may not be thread-safe at all (and it needs to be thread-safe in order to use it in a multithreaded server environment like ASMX).

Comment: yeah, that is the problem. do you know if there is some way to fix it on .net level or it is something must be changed in the properties of vb6 project?

Comment: It's not just properties. The component must be designed for multithreading and must be thoroughly tested in a multithreaded server environment. An example is the Office Automation components from Microsoft Office. They are designed to be used from Office Add-ins and other code running _on the desktop_. When used from a web service or ASP.NET site, they either don't work, or else fail in bizarre ways.